# why does it return undefined from this redux dispatch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I fetch an object named project that contains one array QS and two id's that i want to dispatch a new action for each of them.  the first dispatch returns the array correctly

```
.then((project) => dispatch(lastProjectFetchDataSuccess(project.qs)))
```

but the other two does return undefined?
the object that i'm fetching:

```
{qs:[objects],qpId: "an ID",projectId: "another ID"}
```

the action:

```
export function lastProjectFetchData(url, owner) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(lastProjectIsLoading(true));
    fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        owner: "charlie",
        projectName: "charliesprojekt"
      }),
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    })
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw Error(response.statusText);
        }

        dispatch(lastProjectIsLoading(false));

        return response;
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(project => dispatch(lastProjectFetchDataSuccess(project.qs))) // returns the array
      .then(project => dispatch(qpIdFetchDataSuccess(project.qpId))) // returns undefined
      .then(project => dispatch(projectIdFetchDataSuccess(project.projectId))) // returns undefined
      .catch(() => dispatch(lastProjectHasErrored(true)));
  };
}
```

Comment: make sure to always return in promises. Either that or use Promise.All[] for multiple promises

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning the `project` from your third `then` callback, so the following `then` callbacks will get `undefined`.

You could do this instead:

```
.then(response => response.json())
.then(project => {
   dispatch(lastProjectFetchDataSuccess(project.qs));
   return project;
}) 
.then(project => {
   dispatch(qpIdFetchDataSuccess(project.qpId))
   return project;
 }) 
.then(project => {
  dispatch(projectIdFetchDataSuccess(project.projectId));
  return project;
})
.catch(() => dispatch(lastProjectHasErrored(true)));
```

You can also do it all in the same `then` callback instead:

```
.then(response => response.json())
.then(project => {
   dispatch(lastProjectFetchDataSuccess(project.qs));
   dispatch(qpIdFetchDataSuccess(project.qpId));
   dispatch(projectIdFetchDataSuccess(project.projectId));
}) 
.catch(() => dispatch(lastProjectHasErrored(true)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the call to `dispatch` instead of the project in the third `then`, so the following `then`'s receive the result of `dispatch()` which probably is `undefined`.